# How to include lib3ds to qt project?

Tags: qt, import, 3ds

I'm using QT 5 with QGLWidget for opengl and need to import some 3ds models. Some people suggested me to use [lib3ds](https://code.google.com/p/lib3ds/), but i cant figure how to use it right.In my .pro 
file i wrote this: `INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Chrome downloads\lib3ds-1.3.0"` 
but when i'm including f.e. "lib3ds/file.h" and using method `lib3ds_file_load()` it says "error: undefined reference to `lib3ds_file_load'". Can you tell me how to include lib3ds to my qt project right?

Comment: Did you add the lib3ds headers and sources in your project? `SOURCES += file.c` and `HEADERS += file.h`? You might need to include more than that, but thats just an example. [Read about qmake](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you want to include library in your project you should either include *implementation* of your library as c/c++ sources using SOURCES += ..< implementation files> OR add compiled library source, providing LIBS += -L  -l